#  NSOperationQueue problem with 1 maxConcurrentOperations

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am confused and need your support.
I am implementing synchron http requests in separate thread and therefore I want to
use NSOperationQueue .
But there is a one problem connected with following:
When current request failed,I am going to do another recovery request,this means I should 
add new prior item to my queue and after that repeat that request which  failed  .

Thanks for help

Comment: What's the problem?  You don't want the two operations going on concurrently, do you?

Comment: So?  setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1 and then enqueue the recovery request followed by the repeat of the failed request.  Is there a problem?